# split function not working on new lines

Tags: php

Hi I have simple split script and I am splitting a string on new line that has many new lines characters in it. Here is the code :

```
<?php
   $string = $argv[1]; // CASE 1: COMMAND LINE ARGUMENT.
   echo "String is : $string\n";
   //$string = 'Hello Shakir\nOkay Shakir\nHow are you ?'; //CASE2: SINGLE QUOTE.
   $string = "Hello Shakir\nOkay Shakir\nHow are you ?"; //CASE 3: DOUBLE QUOTE.
   $lines = array();
   $lines = split("\n", $string);

   foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
      echo "line is : $line\n";
      //var_dump($line); 
   } 
?>
```

It works fine when I use CASE 3 in the code, but it doesnt work when I use either CASE1 or CASE 2 (Only CASE 3 works fine). Can anybody please shed some light on this ?

This is how I run it on command line(linux machine) :

```
php my_script.php "Hello Shakir\nOkay Shakir\nHow are you ?"
```

In this case when I print $argv[1], it prints the entire string but it treats it same as CASE2 (with single quotes).

UPDATE :

Many of you have said what the cause of the issue is and not the answer to it. However, knowing the cause helped me fix it. So the answer is :

ANSWER :

Instead of using \n in double quotes ("\n"), use single quotes ('\n') :

```
$lines = split('\n', $string);

OR

$lines = explode('\n', $string);
```

However split counts '\' also as a character and I dont know why. But explode is correct. Since split is deprecated I dont have done much research on this.

Thank you for all who let me know that split is deprecated.

Comment: Don't use `split`.  It's deprecated in favor of `preg_split` for regular expressions, and `explode` for strings.

Comment: seems to work fine for me...although, I'd use explode() instead of split().

Comment: @Nick have you even read the question..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CASE1 and CASE2 will not work for a simple reason, because `\n` is evaluated as a literal `\n` and not a newline character.

Only CASE3, with the double quotes, will evaluate `\n` as a newline.

Also, the function `split()` is deprecated. Try using `explode()` instead.

Comment: [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) also deserves mention I think :)

Comment: It's also not fit here, he wants to split by a string, not by a pattern, so there's no need to use it :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because '\n' not outputs new line, and not interpritate as new line, so in CMD too you don't pass new lines;

Also, `split()` is deprecated, use `explode()`;

Answer (score 1):

The big difference between using single quotes '' and double quotes "" are for automatic replacement inside of strings.

Using "" will enable replacement of variables and usage of escape sequences while '' doesn't support this.

```
$name = 'Mathieu';
$case1 = "Hi this is $name speaking\nPleased to meet you!";
echo $case1;

//Will result in 
Hi this is Mathieu speaking
Pleased to meet you!
```

While using single quotes will yield:

```
$name = 'Mathieu';
$case1 = 'Hi this is $name speaking\nPleased to meet you!';
echo $case1;

//Will result in 
Hi this is $name speaking\nPleased to meet you!
```

All escape sequences possible are:

```
\n Line feed (dec 13)
\r Carriage return (dec 10)
\t Tab (dec 8)
```

Relative to your question about line feeds, note that \n, \r, \r\n are using in different combination depending on the OS and information coming from a Windows OS usually features \r\n while linux only has \n. MacOS used to or still features only \r i think, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

[Single-quoted strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) are not supposed to expand all the escape strings like /n.